# Consulta MySQL carregando table com botão buscar

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, mysql

estou precisando de um help.

Preciso fazer um botão de Busca, pegar os parâmetros de alguns selects(combobox) e atualizar uma table abaixo dos filtros.

Porém não sei bem como fazer isso, para carregar a cada clique no botão.

Segue código que já fiz:

```html
<?php
require_once("conecta.php"); 
?>
<table>
<tr>
 <td>
 Marca:<select>
  <option>Selecione...</option>
   <?php 
   $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sis_marca");
   while($linha = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { ?>
   <option value="<?php echo $linha['cod_marca'] ?>"><?php echo $linha['desc_marca'] ?></option>
   <?php } ?>
  </select>
 </td>
 <td>
 Modelo:<select>
 <option>Selecione...</option>
   <?php 
   $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sis_modelo");
   while($linha = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { ?>
   <option value="<?php echo $linha['seq_modelo'] ?>"><?php echo $linha['desc_modelo'] ?></option>
   <?php } ?>
  </select>
 </td>
 <td>
 Tipo Modelo:<select>
 <option>Selecione...</option>
   <?php 
   $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sis_tipo_modelo");
   while($linha = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { ?>
   <option value="<?php echo $linha['seq_tipo'] ?>"><?php echo $linha['desc_tipo'] ?></option>
   <?php } ?>
  </select>
 </td>
 <td>
 <input type="submit" value="Buscar" name="g_marca" />
 </td>
</tr>

</table>
<table border="0">
<tr bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
   <td width="300"><b>Marca</b></td>
   <td width="300"><b>Modelo</b></td>
</tr>
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM sis_tipo_modelo_oleo";

$resultado = mysql_query($query);
while ($linha = mysql_fetch_array($resultado)) {
 $cod_marca = $linha["cod_marca"];
 $cod_modelo= $linha["cod_modelo"];

?>
<tr>
      <td><? echo $linha['cod_marca']; ?></td>
      <td><? echo $linha['cod_modelo']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: André se você precisa que ao selecionar resultados distintos dentro dos selects haja uma alternância de dados dentro da página abaixo do formulário conforme a seleção, precisará de jQuery e Ajax para requisitar o banco.

Answer (score 6):

Para que ao clicarem no botão `Buscar` seja realizada uma consulta à base de dados que te irá permitir obter novos elementos para colocar na tabela deverás fazer uso de JavaScript e o método Ajax para detetar o clique e despoletar uma comunicação com o servidor:

**Exemplo com a framework jQuery:**

```js
$('input[name="g_marca"]').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  $.ajax({

    type: "POST",
    url: $('#meuFormulario').attr("action"),
    data: $('#meuFormulario').serializeArray(),
    beforeSend: function(xhr, opts) {

      // código antes de comunicar com o servidor
      // util para validar dados, etc...

      // podes chamar xhr.abort(); para cancelar a comunicação
      // com o servidor caso a validação tenha falhado
    },
    success: function(dados) {

      // código após comunicação com o servidor
      // onde recebemos na variavel 'dados' o
      // output que o servidor enviou

      // aqui é onde preparas o novo HTML para
      // atualizar a tua tabela.
    }
  });
});
```

### O que está a ser feito:

É anexado um evento de clique ao teu botão com o nome `g_marca`:

```js
$('input[name="g_marca"]').click(function(e) { /* ... */ });
```

Chamamos o método [`preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) <sup>(Inglês)</sup> no evento de clique designado por `e` para cancelar qualquer comportamento nativo associado ao mesmo:

```js
e.preventDefault();
```

Executamos uma solicitação HTTP assíncrona (Ajax) onde para o efeito fazemos uso da função [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) <sup>(Inglês)</sup>:

```js
$.ajax({

  // método de comunicação com o servidor 'GET' ou 'POST'
  type: "POST",

  // endereço destino onde está o ficheiro que vai receber a comunicação
  // e devolver os dados que pretendemos 
  url: "http://www.example.com/atualizaTabela.php",

  // código a ser executado antes da comunicação iniciar
  beforeSend: function(xhr, opts) { },

  // código a ser executado após a comunicação ter sido realizada com sucesso
  success: function(dados) { }
});
```

### Considerações:

Para que o teu HTML esteja bem construído, os teus elementos que compoem o formulário devem efetivamente estar dentro da marcação de uma formulário:

```html
<form action="http://www.example.com/atualizaTabela.php" id="meuFormulario">
  <!-- Caixas de seleção, botão de envio entre outros -->
</form>
```

Desta forma, e conforme pode ser visualizado no código de exemplo no início da resposta, consegues sem grande trabalho obter os valores que pretendemos enviar para o servidor e obter o respetivo endereço onde se encontra o ficheiro destino:

```js
// Recolher do formulário com o ID 'meuFormulario' o conteúdo do atributo 'action'
url: $('#meuFormulario').attr("action"),

// fazendo uso do método 'serializeArray()' convertemos todos os dados
// escolhidos no formulário numa string pronta a enviar para o servidor
data: $('#meuFormulario').serializeArray(),
```

Saber mais sobre o método [`.serializeArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/serializearray/) <sup>(Inglês)</sup>.

Outra grande vantagem em ter o HTML na sua forma correta é o *fallback* para os casos em que o utilizador está com o JavaScript desativado, onde o formulário com a `action` definida e o botão de `submit` vão permitir que a página funcione normalmente, sendo os dados enviados para o servidor pelo próprio formulário, evitando assim uma quebra de usabilidade.